# Each item in listbox to navigate to a different page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a listbox for a fruits app. I want each item in the listbox, when selected, to take you to a different page that tells the user more about the fruit. I know the code for navigating to one page but I have having trouble using the switch case statements to navigate to several pages. Here is the code:

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,14,-10">
<phone:LongListSelector HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="432" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446" Margin="7,129,0,0"/>
        <ListBox Margin="0,-12,0,52" Name="FruitListbox" SelectionChanged="fruitList_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="230">
                        <Image Name="Image" Width="100" Height="250" Source="{Binding Image}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin= "0,0,10,0"></Image>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="lBtn" Width="370" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="350">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Red"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Foreground="Aqua"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace Carifruits
{
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
 {
    ObservableCollection<Fruit> fruitiness = new ObservableCollection<Fruit>();

public MainPage()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    Fruit fruit1 = new Fruit
    {
        Name = "Abricot",
        Description = "Classified with the Plum",
        Image = "http://img.xooimage.com/files68/5/1/1/abricot-gp14-1--30f6578.jpg",

    };
    Fruit fruit2 = new Fruit
    {
        Name = "Breadfruit",
        Description = "Species of flowering tree",
        Image = "http://nickandmiri.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/breadfruit2.jpg",



    };
    Fruit fruit3 = new Fruit
    {
        Name = "Coconut",
        Description = "Can refer to the entire Coconut Palm",
        Image = "http://www.internationalcoconut.com/coconuts.jpg",


    };
    Fruit fruit4 = new Fruit
    {
        Name = "Hog Plum",
        Description = "Yellowish plum, related to the Mango",
        Image = "http://streetsmartbrazil.com/userfiles/image/caj%C3%A1.jpg",


    };

    Fruit fruit5 = new Fruit
    {
        Name = "Padoo",
        Description = "Tree-growing bean pods ",
        Image = "http://caribfruits.cirad.fr/var/caribfruits/storage/images/fruits_des_antilles/pois_doux/2376-3-fre-FR/pois_doux.jpg",


    };

    fruitiness.Add(fruit1);
    fruitiness.Add(fruit2);
    fruitiness.Add(fruit3);
    fruitiness.Add(fruit4);
    fruitiness.Add(fruit5);

    LayoutRoot.DataContext = new CollectionViewSource { Source = fruitiness };

       }

public class Fruit
{

    public Fruit() { }

    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }


}

private void fruitList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    {
        if (FruitListbox.SelectedIndex == -1) return;
        Fruit data = FruitListbox.SelectedItem as Fruit;

        switch (data.Description)
        {
            case "fruit1":
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pano.xaml?selectedItem=" + FruitListbox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            case "fruit2":
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pano2.xaml?selectedItem=" + FruitListbox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            case "fruit3":
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pano3.xaml?selectedItem=" + FruitListbox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            case "fruit4":
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pano4.xaml?selectedItem=" + FruitListbox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            case "fruit5":
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pano5.xaml?selectedItem=" + FruitListbox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select From the list!");
                break;




        }


        FruitListbox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
}
}
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Does your code work at all? Are you redirected to any page?

Comment: No it was going straight to the default message when I clicked on any of the items

Answer (score 1):

Your switch statement switches the description of your Fruit object, yet the case comparison values are of ... what exactly? It seems like they're variable names.

In general, it's preferred to switch with Enums or Integers.

In your case, you can try using a switch your your fruit's name, or `data.Name` instead.

```
    switch (data.Description)
    {
        case "Abricot":
            ...
            break;
        case "Breadfruit":
            ...
            break;
        case "Coconut":
            ...
            break;
        case "Hog Plum":
            ...
            break;
        case "Padoo":
            ...
            break;
        default:
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select From the list!");
            break;
    }
```

However, a better way would be using the index of the fruit item in your fruit list.

```
    switch (fruitiness.IndexOf(data))
    {
        case 0:
            ...
            break;
        case 1:
            ...
            break;
        case 2:
            ...
            break;
        case 3:
            ...
            break;
        case 4:
            ...
            break;
        default:
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select From the list!");
            break;
    }
```

Of course, there are even better ways than that. You can avoid using a switch entirely.

```
 var navigateUrlIndex = fruitiness.IndexOf(data) + 1;
 var navigateUrl = String.Format("/Pano{0}.xaml?selectedItem={1}", navigateUrlIndex != 1 ? "" : navigateUrlIndex, FruitListbox.SelectedIndex);

 if (FruitListbox.SelectedIndex != -1) {
     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(navigateUrl, UriKind.Relative));
 }
```

Something like that should point you in the right direction. (not tested)

Comment: I tried the second option and it works great! Thank you so much!